# Relate to an arbitrary Map.Entry in Neo4j using Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to store properties as nodes in my Neo4j graph, which then can be reached using the Spring Data Rest API. (And then later I'd like to find object with same properties in my graph.)
The JSON representation of my object should be like

```
{
  //...
  "properties": {
    "key": "value"
  }
  //...
}
```

The simplest way would be

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
public class ObjectWithProperties {
    //...
    @RelatedTo
    Map<String, Object> properties;
    //...
}
```

Obviously, this does not work, as Map.Entry is not a @NodeEntity.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is `DynamicProperties` as field value which is a one-level map of string-value pairs. But it is stored as node-properties not as relationships to other nodes.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but that is not really what I was looking for. For example, I have user object, which can have different properties (they are not defined at design state). One of this possible properties could be PizzaLover (yes/no). Later, when I want to find all PizzaLovers, I have to use a WHERE in my cypher query with DynamicProperties. Though if I can implement a "dynamic node" somehow, all my Pizzalovers will be related to the same PizzaLover node.